# Reading XML with xerces: Getting type where <nodeName type="typeName">

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

I'm using xerces-c-3.1.1 to read xml files into a C++ program.

I have located a node aNode of type

```
DOMNode*       aNode;
```

and can get the node name using

```
name=aNode->getNodeName();
```

However when I try to use

```
type=aNode->getNodeType();
```

to get the type, the type returned is an integer: ELEMENT_NODE.

I would be most grateful if someone could tell me how to write code that enables me to tell whether a node is of name "nodeName" and of type "typeName".  I know how to do the former part using

```
if(wcscmp(name, L"nodeName")==0)
```

but do not know how to do the latter part.

Comment: I fixed your formatting.  Please click the "edit" button to see how it's done for future reference (and see also the help link in the editor).

Answer (score 0):

`DOMNode::getNodeType` is not shorthand for "get the attribute named `type` and return it as a string." It does exactly what it says: retrieves the DOM type of the DOM node. DOM nodes are typed objects: elements, text, attributes, processing instructions, comments, CDATA, etc.

The DOM type of the DOM node has *nothing* to do with what just happens to be stored in the `type` attribute of an element node. That's for you to get for yourself, using regular attribute accessing syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the type from the schema of the XML instance. It would be easier to get the type information on parsing the file using Xerces than after the XML is already parsed and available as a DOM tree. If this is an option for you take a look here: [get-schema-data-types-from-xerces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858889/get-schema-data-types-from-xerces) The answer at the link describes how to get access to the schema types on parsing the file using the Xerces SAX parser.

If this is not an option for you, you need to keep the (DOM) parser you used to load the XML and also get access to the grammar which was generated from the schema on validating the file... At the end much more effort.

Edit: Ok, after looking at the title of the question I'm more confused if you just want to get the type attribute or the schema type... However, if you want to get access to the attributes just use [getAttributes](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#53957cd54f9f818c70f0f47f1c60b34a) and then [getNamedItem](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNamedNodeMap.html#bfefdac5bf23757f82bec7d37b57e2f3) to get the attribute you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to translate the name from XMLStr to char*

```
char* temp2 = XMLString::transcode(aNode->getNodeName());
std::cout << "The current node name is " << temp2 << std::endl;
```